# Celery flower doesn't work under supervisor managment

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, flower

I have Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS running as a vagrant environment under virtualbox. In this box I have this configuration:

- supervisor 3.0b2
- python 3.4 under virtualenvironment
- celery 3.1.23
- flower 0.9.1

A flower configuration under supervisor is:

```
[program:flower]
command=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/python /vagrant/meridian/meridian/manage.py celery flower --loglevel=INFO -conf=/vagrant/meridian/meridian/meridian/flowerconfig.py
directory=/vagrant/meridian/meridian
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/flower-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/flower-stderr.log
priority=997
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=5
```

The flowerconfig.py is an empty file. So all the values are default. Host is localhost and port is 5555.

When I run flower from a command line:

> vagrant@localhost> flower

it is run as it should and I see the tasks result in my browser, visiting an address localhost:5555.

netstat shows me the ports that are listened:

> vagrant@localhost> netstat -l | grep 5555

```
tcp        0      0 *:5555                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5555               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

So, it is OK.

When I run flowe under supervisor in this way:

> vagrant@localhost> sudo supervisorctl start flower

it starts as it should. Netstat shows that port 5555 are listened. But a query from a browser just hangs.

Why flower doesn't reply under supervisor ?

Comment: Dont run flower as vagrant user, run it exactly like the command u are providing to supervisorctl. /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/python /vagrant/meridian/meridian/manage.py celery flower --loglevel=INFO -conf=/vagrant/meridian/meridian/meridian/flowerconfig.py within the directory /vagrant/meridian/meridian

Comment: @lapinkoira I have tried this approach and it doesn't work. However I figured out that issue a command from supervisor config as is doesn't work too, because it is not the same as this sequence: 

1) workon meridian
2) flower -- ... (flower command appeared only after virtual environment is activated)

So, now I need to figure out how to run two mentioned commands in one supervisor config section.

Comment: You dont need workon if you are using your python bin inside the virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. 
The problem was that I ran flower not under my virtual environment. I added a shell file "start_flower.sh":

```
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/meridian/bin/activate
workon meridian
exec flower --conf=/vagrant/meridian/meridian/meridian/flowerconfig.py
```

and it started works as it should.

Then I rewrited supervisor's configuration for flower in this way:

```
[program:flower]
command=bash -c "/vagrant/meridian/meridian/start_flower.sh"
directory=/vagrant/meridian/meridian
user=vagrant
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/flower-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/flower-stderr.log
priority=997
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stderr_logfile_backups=5
stopasgroup=true 
killasgroup=true
```

and now everything is good.

Note: I want to draw your attention to fact that I run flower in shell file with "exec":

```
exec flower --conf=/vagrant/meridian/meridian/meridian/flowerconfig.py
```

I use this there because when I use that construction:

```
flower --conf=/vagrant/meridian/meridian/meridian/flowerconfig.py
```

I had a problew - shell file process was terminated with:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop flower
```

But flower process was working anyway!

So if you would face with such kind of problem always use 'exec'.
This is a good additional information for such cases:

http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html